# Change color of button without changing class

Tags: jquery, html, css

I'm new to jQuery and I need when I click to change color of button without changing all class. How I can do that.

```
<div class="button">First button</div>
<div class="button">Second button</div>
<div class="button">3 button</div>
<div class="button">4 button</div>

$('.button').on('click', function() {
    $('.button').css('background-color', '#C00');
})

.button {
    background-color: #9C0;
    height: 50px;
    width: 100px;
    margin-top:5px;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/nJ895/

so when I click on first button I need to change color just on clicked button not on all buttons so is there any way to do that?

UPDATE:

sorry I try your solution but my code is more complex and dont work with that:
http://jsfiddle.net/nJ895/7/

Here I need to solve some problems so When I click on "1 button" this button must change the color but if I click on "2 button" then "1 button must lose the color" and "2 button get the color" ... this not be afect the second "1 button" and "2 button" in other div which must work in the same way... please HELP. also #id_ is not important in this case but I need it here to show all code.

Comment: also sorry for my english and I dont want to write a different class for all buttons

Comment: You can have more than one class per element. The "clean" way would be to add a new class to the button in addition to the existing one.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/nJ895/8/

Comment: NO, this is no my question you put above! and why I get minus - ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$('.button').on('click', function() {
    $(this).css('background-color', '#C00');
});
```

Updated demo: http://jsfiddle.net/nJ895/1/

Since you're new to jQuery, I'll explain what's going on. In your original code, you're selecting all nodes with the class of `.button` and binding a click event to all of them. When any of them get clicked, you are re-selecting all the nodes again and applying the CSS *to all of them*. The `$(this)` object will point to the node that is bound to the event that just happened and only apply the CSS to that appropriate node.

I'd recommend thinking about adding a new class instead of applying literal CSS. It will allow you to keep your style out of your JavaScript code.

**CSS**:

```
.button {
    background-color : #9C0;
    height           : 50px;
    width            : 100px;
    margin-top       : 5px;
}
.button.active {
    background-color: #C00;
}
```

**jQuery**:

```
$('.button').on('click', function() {
    $(this).toggleClass('active');
});
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/nJ895/3/

Or if you only want one button selected at a time:

```
$('.button').on('click', function() {
    $(this).addClass('active').siblings().removeClass('active');
});
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/nJ895/5/

Comment: thanks for help, I integrate your code into my but still dont work

Comment: Care to explain the downvote? You have an error: `Uncaught ReferenceError: setQuality is not defined ` It has nothing to do with my solution. Cheers.

Answer (score 0):

try using `$(this)`

```
$(this).css('background-color', '#C00');
```

In your case you were targeting all the buttons with a collection named `$('.button')`. You need to capture event to the current object which got the event.

Comment: Repetitive. The other answer says the same thing but does it better.

Comment: @iambriansreed explaination came before other answer here.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use `this` to target the clicked element

```
$('.button').on('click', function() {
    $(this).css('background-color', '#C00');
})
```

---

But the more correct way for changing the colors is to use an additional class

**CSS**

```
.button {
    background-color: #9C0;
    height: 50px;
    width: 100px;
    margin-top:5px;
}
.button.active{
    background-color: #c00;
}
```

**jQuery**

```
$('.button').on('click', function() {
    $(this).addClass('active');
});
```

Demo at http://jsfiddle.net/nJ895/2/

Comment: @iambriansreed what comment ? (*it **is** necessarily better in this case*)

Comment: @iambriansreed I suspect the OP doesn't want to use class only because he doesn't know that it could be used.

Answer (score 0):

```
jQuery('.button').live('click', function() {
    jQuery(this).css('background-color', 'red');
})
```